# JSON Decoding Perl - malformed JSON string

Tags: json, perl

I am getting data from MYSQL Database that is stored in JSON format when I try to decode it I am getting error Malformed JSON any idea ?
$VAR1 is variable that\I get from Database

```
    use JSON;
    use Data::Dumper;

    $VAR1 = [ '{"description":[""],"last_modified_date_min":[""]}' ];

    $DecodeS = decode_json($VAR1);

    print Dumper $DecodeS;
```

malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "ARRAY(0x7f8674002ee8...")

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#decode_json) for the JSON module's `decode_json` function? That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ ... ]` creates an array and returns a reference to that array, so `$VAR1` contains a reference. You are passing this reference (which happens to stringify to `ARRAY(0x7f8674002ee8)`) to `decode_json` instead of a JSON string.

You want

```
$VAR1 = [ '{"description":[""],"last_modified_date_min":[""]}' ];

decode_json($VAR1->[0])
```

or

```
$VAR1 = '{"description":[""],"last_modified_date_min":[""]}';

decode_json($VAR1)
```